# new.livestream.com API to get RTSP

Tags: api, rest, rtsp, live-streaming

I need to get an RTSP stream of a livestream.com account. I was reading some of the API documentation for livestream.com, but they have a new website (new.livestream.com), and I cannot find any API documentation talking about that. Does anybody knows if there is an API for the new livestream.com website which allows me to get an RTSP stream? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

I Know this is a bit old, but i was asking that very same question and i this is how i've done it:

I've found this URL/API call, for the new livestream, to get the details of an event's stream

```
http://new.livestream.com/api/accounts/[account_id]/events/[event_id]/viewing_info
```

This gives you a JSON response with details of streams for that event, including the URL of the RTSP stream (streamInfo -> rtsp_url)

Just be sure to call this before playing a livestream event, because the URL changes from time to time (i think they use some sort of load balancing/CDN network or something) and you should get the latest URL each time.

BTW: To get the [account_id] and [event_id] just look at the URL of an event in new.livestream.com the URLs are something like

- http://new.livestream.com/accounts/**[account_id]**/events/**[event_id]**

  - **[account_id]** and **[event_id]** are all numbers

or

- http://new.livestream.com/**[account_id]**/events/**[event_id]**

  - **[account_id]** is a name (like *'tedx'*) and **[event_id]** is all numbers

or

- http://new.livestream.com/**[account_id]**/**[event_id]**

  - **[account_id]** and **[event_id]** are both names (like '*tedx/WallStreet*')

Also, i'm not sure if this is a public API, but it works for now.

Comment: Any idea of whether they have an API documented anywhere for New Livestream? Haven't been able to find anything. Your info has been a lifesaver though!

Comment: also, any idea how to get a JSONP response?

Comment: I think they only support JSON as the response format, but with a specific APP we needed it in XML so I did an intermediate script with PHP that reads the response in JSON and converts it to XML, caching the result for a few secs as a bonus, so I guess you could do the same for other formats.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @pollosss! I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Can we get the api response using php curl ? could any one show me how ?Thanks