# How to make an Android App that show you the Live Video broadcast of a particular user of Facebook when s(he) is Live?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I am going to make an App for Android that will start displaying the Live video of a particular user when (s)he goes Live on Facebook !

I did tried to read [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/exploring-live) and this [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/faq) but find out nothing !

Comment: It appears that the Facebook Live API is for publishing video content, not accessing the video stream (which probably would be in the Facebook app). If that is what you are trying to do, please update your question with what you've tried.

Comment: Yes that what's I am talking about ! @MorrisonChang

Comment: So you didn't find: [Create a Live Streaming APP for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24939768/295004) and [Streaming video from Android camera to server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2550847/295004) in your search?

Comment: Yeah I did find out those ! But where could I get the streaming link for a particular user of Facebook ?

Comment: Ah, from: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#liveAPI Section 19 Live API `Don’t use the API to stream directly from a mobile phone or tablet camera to Facebook.`

Comment: Isn't https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#liveAPI about posting Live videos ?
Do you mean it's impossible ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181379/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-zakawat).